# Difference in Hebrew between חֹ֔שֶׁךְ (ḥō·šeḵ) and וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ (wə·ḥō·šeḵ)

Tags: hebrew

I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide illumination on the difference between the following Hebrew words. Both utilize the same Strong's definition # 2822.

ḥō·šeḵ | חֹ֔שֶׁךְ | Reference example: Isa 45:7

wə·ḥō·šeḵ | וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ | Reference Example: Ge 1:2

Are these the exact same word? Does the inclusion of "we" in "wehosek" changing the meaning at all?

Thank you!

Comment: This question would be a better fit at [Biblical HermeneuticsSE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hebrew grammar isn't on topic here. [Some questions are also accepted at the Judaism site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-dikduk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

khoshekh - חשך means "darkness"

vi'khoshekh - וחשך means "and darkness"

Remembering the following common conjunctions will be useful:

- ו - and
- ה - the
- מ - from
- ב - in
- ש - that

For example, if I say, "bread and water from Christ", it would be

לחם **ו**מים **מ**משיח

Lekhem vi'maim m'mashiakh

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a very useful list of conjunctions!

Comment: You are welcome! בבקשה!

Comment: Small question, if I may bother you a moment further...

In your example of "bread and water from Christ"

לחם ומים

Why does the "and" appear on the right of water, but the "from" appears on the left of Christ?

Comment: Hebrew reads from the right to left. A conjunction attaches to the next word :)

Comment: Right, but specifically, why does the "from" in "from Christ" appear on the other side?

It would be read "Christ from and water"?

Comment: Lekhem (bread לחם) vi'maim (and water ומים) m'mashiakh (from christ ממשיח)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100319/discussion-between--and-rab).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is the same difference as between the English, "darkness," and "and darkness," because the letter—or more accurately, prefix—ו (*waw*) means "and" (among other things, and depending on the context). So yes, it is the same word in both instances, except one simply has a prefixed "***and***" (ו) meaning, "***and*** darkness," instead of "darkness."